# nginx subs_filter with a regexp

Tags: nginx

I have a legacy backend  with some very unmaintaned code that I cannot modify.
The backend adds to every URL some parameters, which I'm stripping with `sub_filter` in the Nginx proxy:

```
 sub_filter '&source=a_dl_track' '';
 sub_filter '&source=b_dl_track' '';
 sub_filter '&source=c_dl_track' '';
```

The previous directives works fine.
But I would like to use `subs_filter` with a regexp and have a single directive.

This is not working, what is wrong?

```
subs_filter '&source=\w+?_dl_track' '';
```

(The module is loaded `load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;`)